# How can an Excel Add-In respond to events in any worksheet?

Tags: vba, events, excel, add-in

Our workbooks are **server-generated SpreadsheetML**, which cannot include *any* VBA code. Creating native Excel files or Excel 2007 XML files is also not an option, unfortunately.

So, I have an Excel Add-In (VBA, not XLL) that each of our users installs to add some extra UDFs, etc. that our workbooks need.

This works great, but now I need to have a macro that needs to execute *every time* the user changes the text in any cell, regardless what workbook they are actively using at the time.

So far, I've created a new Class module (SheetChangeHandler) in my Add-In, with the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)
    Debug.Print "Changed"
    On Error GoTo Finish
    App.EnableEvents = False
    DoWorkOnChangedStuff Sh, Source
Finish:
    App.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In my Add-In, I've added a line to instantiate the new class:

```
Public MySheetHandler As New SheetChangeHandler
```

My understanding is that this should make Excel send the Add-In *all* SheetChange events for all open workbooks, without those workbooks needing to contain any macro code.

But it's not working... no Debug lines, and my DoWorkOnChangedStuff code isn't being called when I change a cell on any worksheet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use the New keyword in the dim statement.  You're telling it to instantiate the class when it's needed, but then you never refer to it again, so it's never needed.  Instead:

```
Public MySheetHandler As SheetChangeHandler

Sub Auto_Open
   Set MySheetHandler = New SheetChangeHandler
End Sub
```

That line in the Auto_Open (which runs at startup) will instantiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

Got info from:
http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/events/creating-application-level.htm
and tried Dick Kusleika's solution but did not get the class module working.
After 2 days of web searching and before give-up I tried this and worked for my.
Considering : "workbooks are server-generated SpreadsheetML, which cannot include any VBA code", also my requirements.

I wrote this in my class module named "ApplicationEventClass":

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ExcelAppEvents As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
     Set ApplicationClass.ExcelAppEvents = Application
End Sub

Private Sub ExcelAppEvents_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5
End Sub
```

And this in my module named "Module1":

```
Option Explicit

Public ApplicationClass As New ApplicationEventClass

Sub ConnectEventHandler()
      On Error Resume Next
      Set ApplicationClass.ExcelAppEvents = Application
End Sub
```

Thats it! I hope this work for you too.
Obviously only change the text color to blue in any worksheet.

Comment: I was able to get it working with Dick's advice. This was over 7 years ago, but I still have an XLA file that does some of this. However, for most situations, I've moved to have the server embed VBA modules as well, which is supported by EPPlus, the library I use to generate Excel files on the server. I blogged here about it with a few details: http://blog.tallent.us/?p=357