# VBA Addins: Events do not work

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

I just want to catch Open and Save Events in the all workbooks (with or without macros).
As I understand I need AddIn with Event -enabled code. I found many examples in Internet. I learned stackoverflow examples, like here: [How can an Excel Add-In respond to events in any worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858691/how-can-an-excel-add-in-respond-to-events-in-any-worksheet)
But it just do not work. Nobody report any problems. So, I think I have simple mistake here.
I have next Addin, for example:

**Class Module (ExcelEventCapture ) - private:**

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents ExcelApp As Excel.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set ExcelApp = New Excel.Application
ExcelApp.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox "ExcelApp OK"
End Sub

Private Sub ExcelApp_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
Wb.Close savechanges:=False
MsgBox "Sorry - you can't create workbooks in this system!"
End Sub
```

**This code placed in ThisWorkbook:**

```
Option Explicit
Private ExcelEvents As ExcelEventCapture
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Set ExcelEvents = New ExcelEventCapture
MsgBox "ExcelEvents OK"
End Sub
```

Each time after save/modify this code I use Add-Ins manager to switch this addin off/on. After it switched ON, I seen "ExcelApp OK", "ExcelEvents OK". But when I create new workbook no Events happens. Other events also do not handled. I try it with 2007/2010 Excel. Result the same.
Please help.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but why would you instanciate a "New Excel Application" instead of `Set ExcelApp = Excel.Application`. Also, you could instanciate the Class in the AddIn itself in `Auto_Open()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not quite right:

**Class Module (ExcelEventCapture)**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ExcelApp As Application

Private Sub ExcelApp_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Wb.Close savechanges:=False
    MsgBox "Sorry - you can't create workbooks in this system!"
End Sub
```

**This code placed in ThisWorkbook:**

```
Option Explicit

Private ExcelEvents As New ExcelEventCapture

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ExcelEvents.ExcelApp = Application
    MsgBox "ExcelEvents OK"
End Sub
```

Comment: To Chris Neilsen: Thank you for answer. I corrected my texts as you wrote here. Also I commented Class_Initialize method (It's correct?). I've seen "ExcelEvents OK". But events still don't work.

Comment: I've run the posted code, it does work for me.  The code in `Class_Initialise` is not required.  Tested on Excel 2010

Comment: Sorry, I have a mistake: ExcelEvents.ExcelApp = new Application. When "new" was deleted all things became worked. This is not typo. I'm really do not understand what I'm doing. Thank you very much for help.