# How to store macros in one file shared among several users? (not PERSONAL.xls)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 20 excel files with Automation written in VBA where the workflow is similar but there is some customizations in each of the files. I would like to have 20 files, each file per task, but I would like to put all macros into one file, with all the customizations. This will simplify fixing/changing the automation.

I want to have basically one file GlobalMacros.xls somewhere in a shared drive which contains all the modules that do not contain customizations, and only have references to it in the proper files.

Personal.xls is not an answer as I do not want users/team members to feel the changes at all.

Please tell me if there is a solution and what are downsides.

Solution 1:
My solution is to make the module in GlobalMacro.xls and then add just a reference to the module in each file. The downside is it could slow down the execution of the macros because the GlobalMacros.xls will be opened and closed in the background each time any module is called out. Also is it possible for several users using these macros at the same time?

Has anyone got any better solutions? Maybe someone had a similar problem in the past.

Comment: Have you considered using an Add-On file? (XLA/XLAM)

Comment: Read how to create an Add-On file. this should be the answer to your problem.

Comment: "I do not want users/team members to feel the changes at all" - exactly what does that mean?

Comment: @Mat'sMug With the personal file all changes of a macro would have to be sent by email to team members and then they would have to make the changes in ther their own personal files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go into a bit more detail about how to use XLAM files properly.

In a network environment, you will want to keep a local copy of the XLAM where you make changes and updates, and once all glitches are worked out, you then copy it to the server where everyone else accesses it. You will want to also make the server copy read-only, which must be reset each time you copy the file to the server. If you dont make it read-only, you will not be able to copy the updated file to the server while anyone has Excel currently open.

In addition, when the users add the Add-On to their Excel, they will be prompted to copy the XLAM file to their local computer, to which they should reply No, as they want to be able to run off the server copy so they can get your updates. I have found that most people instinctively think they should answer Yes to that question.

If they end up answering Yes, then the only way to fix it is to edit thier registry and remove the reference, and then re-add the Add-On.

Comment: That _No_ bits very important.  I don't think I wrote it large enough in the documentation for my project - put it on the front page, in big flashing text.... tattoo it on their foreheads.... whatever it takes as users don't generally read further than the subject on emails.

Comment: Have you got any sources to find more about XLAM files and excel Addins?

Comment: Nothing off the top of my head... What other information do you need?

Comment: @braX I have created the addin for one module. The Addin contains Two worksheets with buttons which I thought are going to be deployed to the target file. Do you know how to deploy the worksheets from the XLAM? I can copy it from the source file but I cannot reference the Add in functions when assigning macros to buttons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858691/how-can-an-excel-add-in-respond-to-events-in-any-worksheet

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by deploy. What type of buttons are you referring to? Ones in the Ribbon? Ones on a Userform?