# Apply worksheet events programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

In Microsoft Excel, I've written some codes for the worksheet **Change** event. Now I want to create a sub and put it in the *personal.xlsb* file so that whenever the user run it, it will apply that **Change** event to the active worksheet.

Is it possible to do so using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of task is best relegated to an Add-in file.  An add-in is nothing more than a bulk-standard Excel file that gets opened automatically when you open Excel. Addins are easier to distribute than say code in the Personal Macro Workbook...you just email the file along with instructions on how to install it. You can even use a non-addin macro file with a 'click me' button that saves the file as an addin and installs it automatically. Google will turn up examples of this kind of thing.

Might be worth investing in a book such as John Walkenbach's Power Programming with VBA or Bovey et al's Professional Excel Development.

There's also plenty of questions about this kind of thing here at SO, including this one on how to amend the events to work on any worksheet:
[How can an Excel Add-In respond to events in any worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858691/how-can-an-excel-add-in-respond-to-events-in-any-worksheet)

Comment: I'm thinking of creating an add-in too, so I will look into it. But other answers are helpful as well so thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

@Gary's Student's approach I think a very sensible way to do this though, as also mentioned, an add-in is a common way to do this.

If you are interested in how you might add it via code each time see the following construct. It introduces you to the key elements though you would tweak.

```
Public Sub AddWorksheetEventCode()
'Tools > references > Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 
'Trust access to VBA model

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim xLine As Long

    wb.Worksheets.Add After:= wb.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index)
    Set wsNew = ActiveSheet

    With wsNew
        Set xPro = wb.VBProject
        Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents(wsNew.Name)
        Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

        With xMod

            xLine = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "myFirstCodeLineForEvent"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "myNextLine" 'etc

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do *(there may be other approaches)*:

1. Create a template worksheet *(it can be in `Personal` or another workbook)*.  The template will contain the proper column widths, row heights, labels, formulas, etc.  It will also contain any necessary worksheet code like Selection or Change Events.  It will also contain any code associated with Forms on the sheet.
2. Write some code *(resident in the destination workbook)* that will copy the template sheet to the destination workbook.