# How do I make a VBA Add-In which executes code upon creating a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, templates, events, add-in

Whenever I create a new excel worksheet I always go through the *View* menu and disable Gridlines, and so I thought I'd make it so that they are disabled as a default.

I've tried using templates for this but that will only work for the first worksheet which is why I now want to run the following code whenever a worksheet is created on any workbook.
    `ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False`
I included this line in the following method on a workbook which I saved as a .xlam file and later installed, but that didn't disable the gridlines

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
End Sub
```

Can somebody tell me what code might work? I just need this code to run every time I create a new worksheet regardless of the book. It might be that What I need is not an Add-In, really what I'm looking for is for a way to automatically disable gridlines on all worksheets.

Comment: Mind you, the code I tried was written as a workbook event.

Comment: I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858691/how-can-an-excel-add-in-respond-to-events-in-any-worksheet?rq=1 but I couldn't get the answer to work.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)